# Everything about gnome is too small

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, display, display-settings

I recently install linux on my new laptop, it has a 1920x1080 display. On windows all was ok, but on gnome everithing is too small, even the website. here are the screenshots:
[image: File Manager]

[image: Firefox]

I see that there is a scale option in settings but there is only a 200% scale option and it is too big. There is a metod to scale everything a little? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried changing the actual resolution?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Yes but if i scale down the resolution i lose video quality